# How to add a full colored page in scrbook when using geometry?

Tags: color, geometry, pdfpages

I have designed a cover for a document that has a totally black background. See MWE 1:

```
\documentclass{article}

% PACKAGES LOADING

\usepackage{xcolor}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\pagecolor[rgb]{0,0,0}
\color[rgb]{1,1,1}

\begin{document}

SOME FANCY TITLE

\end{document}
```

I then introduce this black page to my main document, as follows. See MWE 2:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
    
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{geometry}    
\geometry{a4paper,textwidth=5.6in,hmarginratio=1:1,textheight=9.5in,vmarginratio=1:1,heightrounded}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[]{MWE 1.pdf}

\end{document}
```

This is the (rather ugly) output:

[image]

My question is: **how can I get rid of the white stripes on the top and the bottom of the page?** By commenting either the `geometry` settings or changing the `documentclass` to article, the inclusion works as it should and the white stripes are gone. However, neither is a valid option for me. What would you?

Comment: Just use `\pagecolor[rgb]{0,0,0}` also in the second document?

Comment: **Thank you** for your comment. Unfortunately, your suggestion makes my entire document go black, which is far from the desired output.

Comment: You can make a single page black, can't you? Just use `\nopagecolor` after the page in which you include the pdf.

Comment: **Thank you** for your comment. While I can do as you suggest, that makes that page go entirely back, thus making the `SOME FANCY TITLE` disappear. Still, far from the desired output.

Comment: Your first document has letter format and your second is A4. Is this on purpose?

Comment: **Thank you** for your comment. Certainly the difference in the formatting was not intentional at all. Specifying the same size for all documents solved the problem. Do you want to post it as answer or should I delete the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Andreas Matthias in the comments, the problem is that `\documentclass{scrbook}` has A4 size, whereas `\documentclass{article}` has letter size. Making sure that both documents have the same page size solves the problem. See the MWE 1:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}    
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\pagecolor[rgb]{0,0,0}
\color[rgb]{1,1,1}

\begin{document}
SOME FANCY TITLE
\end{document}
```

As well as MWE 2:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,textwidth=5.6in,hmarginratio=1:1,textheight=9.5in,vmarginratio=1:1,heightrounded}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[]{MWE 1.pdf}
\end{document}
```

And we get the desired output!

Answer (score 2):

I just tried out the suggestions from the comments above, and got.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
    
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{geometry}    
\geometry{a4paper,textwidth=5.6in,hmarginratio=1:1,textheight=9.5in,vmarginratio=1:1,heightrounded}

\begin{document}
\pagecolor[rgb]{0,0,0}
\includepdf[]{MWE1.pdf}% no space in file name
\clearpage\nopagecolor
test
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: **Thank you** for your answer. Unfortunately, your code displays a completely black page for me. So, for whatever reason, I do not get the same output you get. Just in case it makes any difference, I'm using overleaf.com as my editor.

Comment: @Héctor OK, sorry to hear that. I used pdflatex on an updated TeXLive 2020 installation. Maybe this information will allow others to find out what is going on.

Comment: Hopefully somebody will know! Although I can't accept your answer because it doesn't solve my problem, you got my upvote(s). **Thank you** for giving it a try!